# How to reference CSS from libraries installed via npm?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, npm

So for example say I installed something:

```
npm install --save something
```

and it downloads into

```
./node_modules/something/
```

and it has a folder in there perhaps called `styles` and *in* that folder you have `something.css`. How would I include that css file in my html document (if my html document was along-side the `node-modules` folder?

I mean I *could* do this in my html head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/something/styles/something.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

But it feels wrong to go dig in your `node_modules` directory for stuff. Especially if the html document perhaps needs to get minified and then thrown into some `./dist/` directory. Because then the path to `something.css` is off..

Isn't there a way to simply just go:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="something.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

in your html document - regardless of where it's sitting in your project structure - and it'll just know where to go find that css file?

Comment: What other tools are in your tool kit ? are you concatenating something.css with some other files or just using it as it is?

Comment: I am currently using Sass that gets compiled via Gulp. The "main" Sass file sitting in ./views/styles.scss .

Comment: Why not use absolute paths?

Comment: Then why don't you just use Gulp to copy something.css to a folder scoped to your web app public assets folder ?

Comment: IMO using bower to install these kind of packages is easier and there are a lot of gulp tasks to include sources (css, js) automatically in html files. Usually this kind of info (the path of the file to load) you are looking for resides inside the package.json or bower.json of each package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package for this called [`npm-css`](https://github.com/defunctzombie/npm-css)

In webpack you can require css like `require('bootstrap.css')`, this is why installing css via npm quite useful

if you don't have it, you can create a npm script task that would require (with fs.readFile) all the css files from the node_modules, compile them into single file (which is what `npm-css` does)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's no need to reference the css files explicitly in your html head.
Because you've already involved the  css library via npm ,once you run `npm start` to run your project , Node.js will load all the node_moudules which also includes the css libraries you need.

Comment: Assuming he's server is based on nodejs.

Comment: Which it is not. It's PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which module loader you are using . For example Webpack 
then please read this link https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/176

Otherwise in your server you need to have node_modules as static file directory and then you can safely do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/something/styles/something.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and it correct no harm in that